# Why can't I change the current file in Far Manager with mouse click, but with ctrl + mouse click?

Tags: conemu, far-manager

I'm using Far Manager within ConEmu.

- I can change the current file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left mouse click,
- I can select multiple files with right mouse click,

but I can't change the current file with a simple left mouse click.

I would expect current file changing with left mouse click, and multiple selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left mouse click.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't select a file with simple left mouse click"?

Comment: And do not mix terms. Selection? Marking? Changing current file? What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant with single file selection the changing of the current file.

Comment: Do you have any similar problems with the Ctrl key in any other applications? The first thing I would want to rule out is some sort of stuck key problem.

Comment: I have no problem in other applications.

Comment: What ConEmu version or bundle you are using? cmder? What if you run `ConEmu.exe -basic -cmd {Far}`?

Comment: It works as expected. :) What is the trick?

Comment: I've found it: `-basic` starts ConEmu with default settings.

Comment: I've made reset in the settings dialog and now it works, as expected.
Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Reset in settings dialog helps:

1. Open "Settings..." dialog of ConEmu from context menu or by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Push <kbd>Reset...</kbd> button in the bottom line
3. Restart ConEmu
4. Run Far Manager
5. Enjoy activating and even drag&drop files by mouse

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  How and to what extent did it help?  What is the procedure to accomplish it?  Thanks.